# Generics query about overloading the method

Tags: java, generics

I was reading this example from [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html) In the first example the docs says it will call the `setData(Object)` method, but when I tried the code it never calls that method, instead it calls the `setData(Integer data)` method.

But when I implement this example it gives the runtime exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException at n.setData("Hello");

```
public class Node<T> {
    public T data;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        System.out.println("Node.setData");
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

```
public class MyNode extends Node<Integer> {
    public MyNode(Integer data) {
        super(data);
    }

    public void setData(Integer data) {
        System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
        super.setData(data);
    }
}
```

But the doc says:

```
MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);
Node n = mn;            // A raw type - compiler throws an unchecked warning
n.setData("Hello");     
Integer x = mn.data;    // Causes a ClassCastException to be thrown.
```

ClassCast Exception will occur at 4th line. It doesn't happen that way.

Comment: Isn't that what Oracle says will happen in that tutorial? You should clarify the question, and probably post your code here by editing the question.

Answer (score 2):

What happens is already explained in the same tutorial.

> - `n.setData("Hello");` causes the method `setData(Object)` to be executed on the object of class `MyNode`. (The `MyNode` class inherited `setData(Object)` from `Node`.)
> - In the body of `setData(Object)`, the `data` field of the object referenced by `n` is assigned to a `String`.
> - The `data` field of that same object, referenced via `mn`, can be accessed and is expected to be an integer (since `mn` is a `MyNode` which is a `Node<Integer>`.
> - Trying to assign a `String` to an `Integer` causes a `ClassCastException` from a cast inserted at the assignment by a Java compiler.

So, as you see, this is what you experienced. The method invocation causes the exception, when trying to assign a String to an Integer.

What's confusing about it is that the comment in the code is perhaps misplaced. It is trying to tell you that the code won't reach line 4 because an exception will be thrown by that point. However, it would be clearer if the comment was in line 3, where the exception is actually thrown.

Comment: This line itself gives the exception n.setData("Hello");

Comment: @Chetan Yes, that's what the tutorial and I are saying. That method invocation throws the exception because the string `"Hello"` can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: I do not feel it is like that :( It should actually give the exception on line 4 then not on line 3 itself

Comment: @Chetan What's causing the exception is the line `this.data = data;` in the `Node` class. `this.data` is supposed to be an integer, but in that method invocation you're giving it a string. Since this is all part of the method invocation, it is line 3 that throws the exception, and not line 4. By creating an instance of `MyNode`, the field `public T data` became `public Integer data`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying , but this line confused from the above conclusion n.setData("Hello"); causes the method setData(Object) to be executed on the object of class MyNode. (The MyNode class inherited setData(Object) from Node.)

Comment: I think author here is talking about the Bridge method setData(object) will be called If you pass the string , so exception will not occur on line 3

Answer (score 1):

When you override the method with generic parameter and overridden method has more specific bound, the following thing occurs. In the basic class bytecode you have the method with erased signature:

```
Object data;

public void setData(Object data) {
    System.out.println("Node.setData");
    this.data = data;
}
```

As the subclass is not generic anymore, your method in bytecode is exactly the same as in source:

```
public void setData(Integer data) {
    System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
    super.setData(data);
}
```

However as you can see this method does not override the superclass method as argument type is different. Nevertheless it must be overridden. To do this the java compiler generates a special *synthetic bridge* method in `MyNode` class:

```
public void setData(Object data) {
    this.setData((Integer)data);
}
```

So here's your cast which fails. When you call `n.setData("Hello")`, it's a virtual call and this synthetic method is called which, of course throws an exception.

You may think that the alternative solution would be not to introduce the bridge method, but during the compilation change the argument type in `MyNode`:

```
public void setData(Object data) {
    System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
    super.setData(data);
}
```

Such solution would introduce much more problems especially with code binary compatibility. The users of your `MyNode` should not know that your class extends something with some generic parameter, it's an implementation detail. They should be able just to call your `setData` with normal `Integer` parameter. You may later change the superclass to remove generic parameter in `Node` (assuming that all nodes are integers now) and the users of `MyNode` class should still work correctly without recompilation.